# Using CMU Graphics Lab Motion Capture Database

Tags: unity

I have been attempting to import [CMU motion capture](http://mocap.cs.cmu.edu/) into Unity through Blender.  I was specifically using actor number 127, action number 3: Run.  I was downloading asf/amc file format.  I then used [amc2bvh](http://vipbase.net/amc2bvh/) to convert it to bvh. (I have also tried the native AMC importer, but it doesn't seem to to work as well) Once it is imported, I save the blend file and import it into Unity.  I change the avatar to be a humanoid avatar and leave the defaults.  This is the result. 
[image: Bad Mocap]

If I add bone rotation constraints to the thighs and limit the rotation on the Z-axis, then that seems to resolve the problem with this particular one.  I would like to fix this a better way that way I can use the rolling animation in such in my game.  If anyone has any idea how to solve this, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest using bvh files from this library
[CMU-BVH](http://www.thetrailerspark.com/downloads/Detailed/CMU/Library/BVH/)

On youtube, check out Benjycook Blender MoCap Addon Tutorial, which uses the same library.
[BenjyCook](http://www.youtube.com/channel/UCxC7A3Mr3s8n0Ub)

Answer (score 1):

Try this port of the CMU collection:

https://sites.google.com/a/cgspeed.com/cgspeed/motion-capture/cmu-bvh-conversion

It contains a few conversions to popular rigs. I've used those a lot and I never had any problems.